# Como ir para o final do ScrollView

Tags: android, rolamento

Tem como eu mandar para o final do  `ScrollView` Quando clicar em um botão?

Tenho um `RadioGroup` e um `Buttom`, os dois estão em um `ScrollView`, quero que quando clicar em um dos `RadioButtom` ir para o final do `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a [função `ScrollView.html#fullScroll`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#fullScroll(int)) usando como argumento [`FOCUS_DOWN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#FOCUS_DOWN) para mover para baixo, e para mover para cima, use [`FOCUS_UP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#FOCUS_UP).